# configure apache to be tested on local server

Tags: apache

How do I configure apache where I can test it on a local server without a DNS? I tried the below but I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

I'm using Centos.

Here is what I did

1. Get IP address with |ip addr show|
2. to etc/hosts I added |92.168.169.128 tst01|.  I got the ip from #1
3. restarted apache |apachectl -k graceful|

In a web browser if I go to `http://tst01/` I get the default Apache page.

Here is my httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerAdmin asdf@example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName tst01
  DocumentRoot /tmp/public_html

  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
  ErrorLog /tmp/apache_logs/error.log
  CustomLog /tmp/apache_logs/access.log combined    
</VirtualHost>
```

I put a very simple index file at: /tmp/public_html/index.html.

The permissions for /tmp/public_html is 755

I can see my index file if I put this in a browser:file:///tmp/public_html/index.html

If I look in /tmp/apache_logs I don't have any logs.  I even tried to open the permissions to 777

Any suggestions on getting my index.html to show up instead the default apache page?

Comment: try changing 92.168.169.128 to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file

Comment: That doesn't work either.  I put the following in the hosts file: `127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost tst01`

Comment: just put 
`127.0.0.1 localhost` and
`127.0.0.1 tst01.net`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the wrong config file.  Centos came with apache installed by default (I installed to a virtual machine) and I installed in a custom dir.  Centos was picking up it's version and never looking at my config.  I did a  to see where the config was located.

Also the /etc/hosts file should be set to 127.0.0.1.